# 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge in visual studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

while i am trying to pull a source to git it shows error as follows"An error occurred. Detailed message: 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge"

I searched and tried those things like:
commit in local repository and pull
remove the untracked files

Both not worked for me.

Comment: Such problem most often occur when line endings changed (CRLF). There are situations where git diff doesn't show a difference but pull (more exactly: merge) doesn't work because of changes. Even the `autocrlf` option doesn't help. In my eyes it's a bug in git. Currently, I have the same problem. And no reproducible workaround yet.

Answer (score 27):

do a stash before pull your changes ,no need to create a new commit to pull new changes

```
git stash;
git pull origin master;
git stash pop;
```

Nicely explained in

[[Official documentaion] git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: git stash gave the message: "No local changes to save". But it still fixed my problem. Wierd.

Comment: @Raghu it isn't weird. `git stash` is specially for the purpose where you don't want to remove all your local changes just to take an update.

Comment: @TajAhmed, I know, but in my case, there were no local changes to stash! But somehow `git stash` before `git pull` worked...

Comment: Same for me! No changes, did a git stash (which confirmed I had no changed by outputing "No local changes to save"). But somehow I could merge afterward!

Comment: I had the exact same experience with VS2015.  git stash > "No local changes to save" git pull origin master > "Already up to date." git stash pop > "No stash entries found."  But before this rigmarol VS would not merge.

Answer (score 6):

I did the following and it cleared things up nicely:

```
git status
git pull
```

Comment: This worked for me but I don't understand why it fixed the issue. Any explanation? Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinChen, Glad it worked for you. I'm not absolutely sure why it works. It's just something I learned at some point and honestly never bothered to question why it works. I've assumed that it just syncs the repository to a state that VS 2013 needs. Without knowing why VS 2013 has the issue, it's hard to say why those two commands actually fix the issue.

Comment: `git pull` returns `Already up-to-date` but it solves the `uncommitted change would be overwritten` when merging in VS2015. Nobody knows why, but it works

Comment: I have the same issue while using VS2015 community to operate Github extension and this works for me.